# Run SQL by Powershell if exist file in folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

Good day

Iam looking way how to run sql command only if exist file/s in specific folder ? I read lot of staff but i cant not fit my skript . I do not want do make SSIS I want do to in Powershell.
Then I will put into MSQL Job Agent powershell script wchich will run every hour . If this Job find .csv file /s then will start other Job.

Thank you for opinion.

```
$SourceFile = "C:\Import\FOLDER\report\Old\test\*.csv"
Action = "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "100.000.000.001" -Query "USE msdb ;   EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'MSSQLJOBNAME' ;"

if(Test-Path -Path $SourceFile)
{
    "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "100.000.000.001" -Query "USE msdb ;   EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'MSSQLJOBNAME' ;"

}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your script?

Comment: @marsze Not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specifying the folder and `*.csv` in a variable is not enough; you have to get the filelist.

for running the sql command in the database `msdb` I added the parameter `-Database`

```
$SourceFilesArray = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Import\FOLDER\report\Old\test\" -Filter "*.csv"

if($SourceFilesArray) {
    # $SourceFilesArray is not empty/contains list of specified files
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "100.000.000.001" -Database "msdb" -Query "EXEC dbo.sp_start_job 'MSSQLJOBNAME'"
} else {
    # run this if $SourceFilesArray is empty/no files found
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "100.000.000.001" -Database "msdb" -Query "EXEC dbo.sp_start_job 'MSSQLJOBNAME'"
}
```